# How to use audio signal from car speaker as transistor switching signal?

Tags: transistors, automotive, led-strip, speakers

I want to make reactive LED strip for my car and I want to make it somehow smart... I figured a schematic like the one below:

[image]

The LED has a 12 V source at the beginning of course. KEY3 is a relay but the case we are considering here doesn't matter, because it's closed

I connected the circuit as shown below but it doesn't work as expected. The LEDs are lit when the radio is on but the volume is zero. I checked the voltage on the speaker wire and it shows about 6 V when the radio is on, and near to 0 V when the radio is off. But I measured it with DC voltmeter.

I know speakers work on audio signal between two terminals, which is basically an AC signal, but I thought connecting the base to one speaker wire would create pulses of voltage between the base and the emitter. Instead, the LEDs are on all the time. When I turn up the volume they seem to start pulsating but they are never really off.

The ground shown on the schematic is the cars mass ground, so it isn't connected to the speaker in any way.

Unfortunately, I don't have an oscilloscope to look at the speaker wire signal.

Is there any way I can connect it so that the LEDs flash to the music?

Comment: In your shematic LED does not have the current restricting resistor. You may burn LED and transistor. And speaker does not have the same ground as your circuit, so it is not closed circuit. Use  optocoupler.

Comment: @user263983 it's an LED strip so it has resistors built in. The LED on the schematic is only a representation of the strip

Comment: @user263983 If I would go for an optocoupler should I connect the LED in the optocoupler to both wires on the speaker?

Comment: Yes. And you may choose optotransistor with bipolar input (two LEDs in parallel, opposite direction) or diodes bridge. Choose resistor properly.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Car radios can have bridged output stages for more output power with 12VDC voltage. The speaker output signal is not at all a voltage against ground. You should use a transformer or optocoupler as isolating element.

You can connect one optocoupler (=the led side) with series resistor in parallel with the speaker. The optocoupler output side feeds base current to the transistor which gives DC to the led stripe. Use 2 optocouplers by connecting the outputs in parallel and the inputs too, but leds to opposite directions to have drive from plus and minus halves of the speaker signal.

DO NOT skip proper calculations or you can pull the smoke out as well from the radio and the leds and their wiring and driver.

Something to think:

- It's possible that you want some smoothing to prevent too sharp led flicker. Designing the drive with proper decay time constant is totally a new problem.
- Any extra electronics in a car is a new possibility to have failures. Making a device which does not disintegrate in car's vibrations is anything but trivial.
- I wouldn't accept disco lights in a car except in case the car is parked.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I made an option to turn on the "disco lights" when I want to, so it's only going to be used when parked. I'm going to try an optocoupler as suggested. I'll try to mount the whole circuit on something spongy or made of rubber so it can withstand the vibrations.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is what's been called a "Color Organ", and knowing that, you should be able to hunt down a better starting point for your schematic.

You are correct (to a point) that "speaker wire would create pulses of voltage between the base and the emitter", but even once you address the issues of isolation and biasing of the transistor, the pulses in the audio are happening so rapidly that you wouldn't percieve them as pulses of light.  (A simple constant tone at middle-C is pulsing more than 500 times a second.)

Color organs typically work by filtering out some frequencies of the audio (with a circuit that resembles one band of a graphic equalizer), detecting the changes in their amplitude (with an envelope detector circuit), and then using that to drive the the transistor's base.  In a crude way, your D9 is doing the envelope detection, but the signal isn't getting smoothed out to capture the slower changes (rhythm), so it's going to turn on and off with all vibrations.  There's a capacitor in an envelope detector to do that smoothing.

Comment: Its only a color organ if it's multiple colors and bandpass filters. Otherwise its a simple sound reactive led. As far as web project names go.